# Wrapping semantic elements with non-semantic elements

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am wondering if can I wrap semantic elements with non-semantic elements for layout purposes. Do screen-readers etc. get only directly childs (like `>` CSS selector) or can I wrap as much as I want?

## Examples

### `div` wrapping `header`

```
<section>
  <main>
    <div>
      <header>
         <h1>Page title<h1>
      </header>
    </div>
    <article>[...]</article>
  </main>
</section>
```

### Another `div`'s wrapping `header`

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <header>
         <h1>Page title<h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add as many [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) and [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) elements as you need.

They don’t change the meaning (unless they have certain attributes, like `lang`, `title`, …), so these snippets are semantically equivalent:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <header>…</header>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div>
  <header>…</header>
</div>
```

```html
<header>…</header>
```