# <main> tag as a column wrapper

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

Let's say that I have a website with a header, two columns under it (one as a wrapper for articles and the other as a sidebar). Now, can I use `main` as a wrapper for those articles:

```
<main>
    (articles here)
</main>
<aside class="sidebar">
    (sidebar here)
</aside>
```

Or should I wrap this `<main>` with `<div>`?

```
<div id="left-column">
    <main>
        (articles here)
    </main>
</div>
<aside class="sidebar">
    (sidebar here)
</aside>
```

In general: can we use semantic tags also for styling/display purposes with CSS (which is normally the domain of `div` elements)?

Answer (score 3):

You should not *add* those semantic elements just because you need CSS hooks, but if your use of the elements is appropriate, it is perfectly fine, and a good practice, to use them *also* as hooks for CSS.

If you need more than your existing elements for styling reasons, add `span`/`div` elements (as they are the only "non-semantic"/[meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487612/1591669) elements).

Adding `span`/`div` around every semantic element you want to style would bloat your markup, and make it harder to understand/maintain. There can be one reason for doing it for the elements introduced with HTML5 (like `main`), though: If you need to achieve a certain styling in old browsers which don’t support these new elements.

Answer (score 2):

"New" HTML5 elements are elements like any other (OK not `input[type="hidden"]` or `head`  ^^ but div or span or p or h6). They bring semantics but when it comes to styling, in browsers supporting them which is IE9+ (except maybe for main), you can `display: flex` them or `float` or `position: relative` or even `display: inline`.
IE8 needed a polyfill named htmlshiv but that's oooold. Don't support IE8 (because MS doesn't even support the OS where it could run!)

I'd include aside as an aside to main and preceding sibling could be an article or section.

```
<main role="main">
  <article><!-- or section? -->
    (articles here)
  </article>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    (sidebar here)
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: `The content inside the <main> element should be unique to the document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms.` > https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Comment: Question is more about "styling with CSS elements that have semantics" and my answer is more detailed in that regard but yes, main element must remain unique in a given page. As described by OP, I think that's what he wants to do (column of a page)